# Transformar timestamp a Unix date - hora 24

Tags: php, json

Tengo un problema el siguiente problema:
Descarga datos de una api los cuales trae los valores en un json

> "clv_nodo": "01PLO-115",
> "Valores": [
> {
> "fecha": "2017-11-07",
> "hora": "1",
> "pml": "1177.12",
> "pml_ene": "1109.73",
> "pml_per": "69.65",
> "pml_cng": "-2.27"
> },
> {
> "fecha": "2017-11-07",
> "hora": "2",
> "pml": "1005.79",
> "pml_ene": "947.64",
> "pml_per": "59.13",
> "pml_cng": "-0.98"
> },
> {
> "fecha": "2017-11-07",
> "hora": "3",
> "pml": "942.56",
> "pml_ene": "886.02",
> "pml_per": "56.78",
> "pml_cng": "-0.24"
> },

.....
hasta la hora 24
el detalle es cuando ocupo strtodate para hacer la conversion de datetime a unixdate guarda todas las horas correctamente menos la 24 la cual sustituye por:
0000-00-00 00:00:00
aqui el codigo que utilizo para hacer el cambio.

```
$json = json_decode($pagina_inicio, true);
        foreach($json as $dato) {
            if(is_array($dato)){
                foreach ($dato as $datos => $value) {
                    if(is_array($value)){
                        $clv_nodo = $value['clv_nodo'];
                        foreach ($value as $key => $value2) {
                            if(is_array($value2)){
                                foreach ($value2 as $key2 => $value3) {
                                    if(is_array($value3)){
                                        $fecha = $value3['fecha'];
                                        $hora = $value3['hora'];
                                        $pml_mda = $value3['pml'];
                                        $ene_mda = $value3['pml_ene'];
                                        $per_mda = $value3['pml_per'];
                                        $cong_mda = $value3['pml_cng'];
                                        $datetime= $fecha.' '.$hora.':00:00';
                                        $fecha_unix = strtotime($datetime);
                                        $identificador = $fecha_unix.'-'.$clv_nodo;
                                        $nodo = $clv_nodo;
                                        $sql = "INSERT INTO node_data_test (fecha_unix,clv_nodo,pml_mda,per_mda,cong_mda,ene_mda,identificador,fechahora) 
                                        VALUES('$fecha_unix','$nodo','$pml_mda','$per_mda','$cong_mda','$ene_mda','$identificador','$datetime')";
```

alguien tiene alguna idea? mi otra solucion era restarle 1 hora a lo que me arroje el json para tener de la hora 00 a la 23 y no tenga este problema.

Comment: Si la hora de 1 a 23 son correctas, menos la 24, entonces puedes modificar la linea correspondiente a esta: `$datetime = $fecha . ' ' . $hora % 24 . ':00:00';` Esto hará que `24` sea convertido en `0`.

Comment: Muchas gracias me diste la idea lo que hice fue poner un if  $hora = $value3['hora'];
                                            if($hora=="24")
                                            $hora="00";

Answer (score 0):

Lo que hice fue convertir en el 24 en 00

```
 $hora = $value3['hora'];
    if($hora=="24")
       $hora="00";
```